# How do I pass response.context back in Watson Conversation API when used in conjunction with Twitter API?

Tags: twitter, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

The idea is I'll use Twitter's streaming api to grab the newest mentions of my account, feed that data to watson convo api and have watson spit out a response; then I'll give that response to twitter again to reply to the person who mentioned me. In order for watson convo api to work properly, I'll have to pass back response.context to watson.

I've got everything down except for the passing back response.context part. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

```
var twitter = require('../statics/twitterAPI_KEY_Dev');
var watson = require('../statics/watsonAPI_KEY_Dev');

function botReplyInit() {
var stream = twitter.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '@Felicia_Bot' });

stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) {
    var dataProcessed = false;
    var data;

    if (!dataProcessed) {
        var data = tweet.text.replace(/@(\w+)/g, '').replace(/#(\w+)/g, '');
        //cleans up the tweet so the @ and # are deleted
    }

    var username = tweet.user.screen_name;
    var statusID = tweet.id_str;
    var endConversation = false;

    var error = {};
    var res = { output: {}, intents: [] };

    processWatson(error, res); 
    //how do we move this intialization outside of the stream.on function so it only 
    //get called once in the entire lifetime of the app??

    function processWatson(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        if (response.output.action === 'end_conversation') {
            endConversation = true;
        }
        if (response.intents.length > 0) {
            var result = '@' + username + ' ' + response.output.text[0];

            twitter.post('statuses/update', {
                status: result,
                in_reply_to_status_id: tweet.id_str
            }, 
            function(err, response) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('I posted ' + result);
                }
            });
        }

        if(!endConversation && !dataProcessed) {
            watson.message({
                input: { text: data },
                context: response.context
            }, 
            processWatson);
            dataProcessed = true;
        }
    }
})
}

botReplyInit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

referring to the API documentation for the message method of the Watson Conversation service - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#send_message

The Response from message contains the context object, which is what you need to return back to the service on subsequent invocations of the message API. On conversation initialisation the context object is not required.

Your application will need to keep a track of the context object, and if you are going to allow multiple simultaneous conversations you will need to be able to map context object to conversation.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying. I rewrote the code so that response.context is passed back. The idea is that once the watson callback function is initialized once, it'll never initialize again; the api call is inside the callback function so it'll just loop back around when there's a reply. However, that doesn't work out since my watson initializing call is inside of the stream.on's callback function, so every time there's a new tweet, even though the context is passed back, the initializing call for watson is called again so the context that was passed back is wiped out.

Comment: If I leave the watson initializing function call outside of the stream.on, I won't be able to call it, since it's defined inside of the stream.on. If I wrap stream.on inside of the watson callback function, it'll create an infinite loop of stream.on calls that won't stop.

Comment: Create an object to hold the context outside the stream.on, and initialise it to a null object. Then pass in the object to every conversation call, including the conversation start, allowing the response to update it.

Comment: Ohhhh and then I would refer the context of the second (real) conversation call to that object each time as well? That is genius!!